# Failed to generate client types - Failed deserializing metadata from server. ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack

Im having [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKqDE.png) error when trying to use the ServiceStackVS feature for generating client DTOs on Visual Studio C# Project.
[image]

I've managed to add a reference to the Service Stack example service to my project without problems.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using the [latest v1.0.15 of ServiceStackVS](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5bd40817-0986-444d-a77d-482e43a48da7) with the latest v4.0.42+ of ServiceStack?

Comment: How can i find out the server version? I dont have access to the server where it is published.

Comment: You can look at the `X-Powered-By` HTTP Header if they haven't removed the default `Config.GlobalResponseHeaders`.

Comment: The header is being overriden by an intermediate server. Unfortunately im not able to determine the version that way.

Comment: Do you have the latest v1.0.15 of ServiceStackVS? Install it from `Tools -> Extensions and Updates...` if not, then restart VS. If the issue persists you can [download the DTO's directly](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Add-ServiceStack-Reference#language-paths) at `/types/csharp`

Comment: Sounds like the URL you are providing might not be the base URL of the server, IE where ServiceStack is listening. For example, if the server is hosted at `/api` you will need to include `/api` in the URL in the dialog. If the server is hosting the metadata at the default location, `{baseurl}/metadata` should load successfully.

Comment: @sanfalero did you manage to generate the server references?